# How to: SLF4J with multiple bindings in a GWT Maven multi-module project?

Tags: gwt, maven, slf4j

I have a GWT multi-module Maven project.
Layout:

```
pom.xml  
client-module  //client side: contains some base classes. I use JDK's java.util.log so that it logs on Firebug's console
server-module  //server side: extends some code from client-module (so it uses JUL) for common behaviour. I use log4j
```

client-module is shared code.
I want to use SLF4J globally but it seems that I cannot use multiple bindings ***(multiple bindings per project, single binding per maven module).***
I would agree, but I want to use a specific SLF4J binding per maven module. 
So in my case would be SLF4J-JDK for client-module and SLF4J-log4j for server-module.

Pieces of relevant code:
**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

**client-module**/BaseFoo.java

```
public abstract class BaseFoo {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseFoo.class.getName());
// ... interesting stuff
}
```

**server-module**/Foo.java

```
public class Foo extends BaseFoo {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseFoo.class.getName());
// ...more interesting stuff
}
```

I have already tried to configure according to documentation, but it doesn't work.
The problem is that SLF4J needs to be GWT ready.
The error I get:

```
[ERROR] Line 23: No source code is available for type org.slf4j.Logger; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

What it means that GWT compiles the BaseFoo class to Javascript (that's why is it in client-module to run on client side) but fails because the classes/source code in SLF4j are not emulated.

Do you have any workarounds? 
Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what does not work.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: I have added some code to make it more clear.

Comment: so just to have something working I've just replaced logging with System.out.println()

Comment: Would be nice if gwt-log addes slf4j support (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/issues/detail?id=18&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Stars%20Summary )